# Careers account list showing random "percentiles" instead of reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The Careers profile account list seems to be showing percentiles, instead of the expected reputation values. What's more, the percentile randomly changes if you refresh the page (and happens to be exactly the same for all sites), which suggests that it's not necessarily a real value either.

[image: Careers account list showing percentiles]

Comment: Seems that this has now been fixed.

Comment: No problem on my side. So probably yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops...nobody saw that, right?

Should be fixed now.